# How to add a DraggableScrollableSheet inside ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```
body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
          child: ListView(
        
                          children:[ 
                            
                            
                            Stack(
                              children: [
                                BuildMainProfile(
              screenHeight: screenHeight,
              screenWidth: screenWidth,
              uid: widget.uid,
              callBack: widget.callBack,
            ),
            DraggableScrollableSheet(
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          return Container(
          color: Colors.blue[100],
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 25,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
            },
          ),
          );
            },
        )
                              ],
                              
                            ),
                           
                      
                           ] ),
        ),
```

The above codes give an error

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
So How can we use  DraggableScrollableSheet inside ListView
ListView is only used because of RefreshIndicator, it serves no other purpose. So is there an Alterntive

Comment: A `Column` fits better than a `ListView` in your case

Comment: I am Still getting the same error after Replacing ListView with Column=> These invalid constraints were provided to RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:    // But I am using RefreshIndicator So with a column I wouldn't be able to see the indicator

Comment: try setting the `mainAxisSize` on the column to `MainAxisSize.min`.